# Cannot create medium visualization for X.radio because network node visualization is not found- Omnet++

Tags: c++, network-programming, omnet++, veins, inet

I am attempting to add the communication ranges of the cars in the Veins_Inet example. I included a
visualizer in the network NED file:

```
visualizer: IntegratedVisualizer {}
```

I also the following line to the ini file:

```
*.node[*].wlan[0].radio.displayCommunicationRange = true        # show range of car
*.visualizer.*.mediumVisualizer.displaySignals = true           # show signals
```

However, I get the following run time error after this event in the event trace:

```
INFO (Ieee80211ScalarRadio)TestScenario.node[0].wlan[0].radio:Radio mode changed from OFF to OFF.

<!> Cannot create medium visualization for 'TestScenario.node[0].wlan[0].radio', because network node visualization is not found for 'TestScenario.node[0]' -- in module (inet::visualizer::MediumCanvasVisualizer) TestScenario.visualizer.canvasVisualizer.mediumVisualizer (id=17), at t=0.1s, event #11
```

What am I missing to make the Veins_Inet scenario display the visuals? I was trying to use tutorials from here for inspiration
https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/visualizer/radiomediumactivity/doc/index.html
but could not get any luck.

Comment: In the past, I've always found it helpful to attach a debugger to the simulation, see exactly in which line it fails, and work backwards from there. In your example, I'm pretty sure that shortly before the error message (`Cannot create medium visualization`) is written out by the code, there is a check in the code to see if an error should be thrown. Investigating what exactly is being checked here might go a long way towards figuring out what should have been different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered this error as well. In my case, I was using INET 4.2 but Veins 5.0. Visualization does not work in for Veins in this version.
You will need to update your veins_inet subproject to use the latest Veins.

Specifically, the version that has this commit:
https://github.com/sommer/veins/commit/4a1459c408338eacb96a699d080e3116a518ac9a#diff-00d2a86e05e87c58818048abab354bf7